# logistic regression with conflicting results, so to speak

Tags: logistic, categorical-data, model, intercept

I was trying to duplicate values by running the same set of data, and my coefficients were different.  there is one 0-1 dependent variable, and there are four 0-1 independent variables.   I found out the reason I was getting different coefficients was that I had run it with the independent variables as nominal, and the person whose data I was trying to duplicate had run them as continuous.  they were actually correct as verified by the interpretation of the intercept along with the actual data (i.e. leaving out variable rank4 as one of the variables gave an interpretation of 79% "ones" when rank4 was set to one, and that is exactly what the data reflected).   so, two questions.  one is why it mattered.  I cannot fathom the mathematics behind it.  secondly, does that suggest that in all cases one should run independent binary variables as continuous?  thanks  John

Answer (score 0):

If your software parameterises categorical predictors as indicator variables with 0 corresponding to the first level (in your case 0) and 1 for the other then the two analyses should give the same result. You use the term nominal to refer to your variables which suggests you are using SPSS which, I believe, parameterises the *last* category as 0 and the first as 1 so you would get different results. I have no idea what Stata nor SAS do.

Comment: thks for response.I used JMP (product of SAS) to do this. but I am still trying to wrap my head around this. There are two things I still do not understand. WHY the continuous gives the appropriate intercept and NOT the nominal (since 0-1's are really nominal), but also, there is something going on behind the scenes,so to speak to get different results.this tells me that to run a logistic regression, one MUST fully understand the nuances involved with independent variables regarding nominal, ordinal, or continuous variables else the interpretation of coefficients will not make sense.

Comment: A quick internet search reveals that SAS uses the same coding as I mentioned for SPSS.